# Django - unsupported format character 'a' (0x61)

Tags: django

I was receiving the following error

```
unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 16

def send_notification_email(sender, **kwargs):
    change = sender
    print "=========================================="
    mail_admins(subject="model %(model) has been changed by %(user)" % 
                            {'model':change.content_type, 'user': change.user},
                message = render_to_string('change_email.html', { 'change': change }) )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the format specifier.

```
%(model)s
```

Comment: It produces the output like model <django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object at 0x025B5330> has been changed by <django.db.models.fields.related
.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object at 0x025B52B0>. Is there any way to change it to proper format?

Comment: Yes. Use a `unicode` as the format specification and make sure your `__unicode__()` methods are properly defined.